Comparing Two Lists Containing Data Frames
I have two lists, one list is for all of the data frames the user added (listOfOriginalDataFrames), and another one is a list of all the data frames the user wishes to display (listOfDisplayedDataFrames). I'm using a QCheckBox, and I'm trying to make my code so that when the user checks the box, that selected data frame will be appended to the listOfDisplayedDataFrames, and when its unchecked, it will be removed. The checkboxes .setChecked are based on if the data frame is in the listOfDisplayedDataFrames.
I have some logic to append and remove the data frame from the listOfDisplayedDataFrames, but its not working. Any suggestions?
# Custom data frame class
class IdentifiableDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    """
    A DataFrame subclass that includes a custom identifier.
    
    Parameters:
    -----------
    *args : list
        Positional arguments passed to the pandas DataFrame.
    custom_id : str, optional
        A custom identifier for the DataFrame.
    **kwargs : dict
        Keyword arguments passed to the pandas DataFrame.
    """
    
    _metadata = ['custom_id', 'name']
    
    def __init__(self, *args, custom_id=None, name=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.custom_id = custom_id
        self.name = name
    
    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return IdentifiableDataFrame
    
    def __finalize__(self, other, method=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Propagate metadata from other to self.
        """
        if isinstance(other, IdentifiableDataFrame):
            self.custom_id = getattr(other, 'custom_id', None)
            self.name = getattr(other, 'name', None)
        return self

# For the drop down menu of all the existing files
    def showDropdownMenu(self):
        menu = QMenu(self)

        for i, df in enumerate(self.excelProcessor.listofOriginalDataFrames):
            item_widget = CustomMenuItem(df.name)

            item_widget.checkbox.setChecked(df.custom_id in [d.custom_id for d in self.excelProcessor.listOfDisplayedDataFrames])

            item_action = QWidgetAction(self)
            item_action.setDefaultWidget(item_widget)
            item_widget.remove_button.clicked.connect(lambda _, idx=i: self.removeDataFrame(idx))
            item_widget.checkbox.stateChanged.connect(lambda state, idx=i: self.updateDisplayedDataFrames(idx, state == Qt.Checked))
            menu.addAction(item_action)

        add_file_action = QAction("Add File", self)
        add_file_action.triggered.connect(self.selectFileButtonClicked)
        menu.addAction(add_file_action)

        menu.exec_(self.selectFileButton.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, self.selectFileButton.height())))

    def updateDisplayedDataFrames(self, idx, checked):
        originalDf = self.excelProcessor.listofOriginalDataFrames[idx]
        customID = originalDf.custom_id

        # If the file is checked
        if checked:
            # If the file is not in the list of displayed data frames, add it
            if customID not in [df.custom_id for df in self.excelProcessor.listOfDisplayedDataFrames]:
                self.excelProcessor.listOfDisplayedDataFrames.append(originalDf)

        # If the file is unchecked
        else:
            if customID in [df.custom_id for df in self.excelProcessor.listOfDisplayedDataFrames]:
                self.excelProcessor.listOfDisplayedDataFrames.remove(originalDf)
        
        self.df = self.excelProcessor.displayedDataFrames
        self.populateTable()
        self.showDropdownMenu()
        print("Excel file processed successfully.")

    # To remove data frames from the list
    def removeDataFrame(self, idx):
        try:
            if 0 <= idx < len(self.excelProcessor.listofOriginalDataFrames):
                df_to_remove = self.excelProcessor.listofOriginalDataFrames.pop(idx)
                custom_id_to_remove = df_to_remove.custom_id

                self.excelProcessor.listOfDisplayedDataFrames = [
                    df for df in self.excelProcessor.listOfDisplayedDataFrames if df.custom_id != custom_id_to_remove
                ]

                self.showDropdownMenu()
            else:
                raise IndexError("Index out of range")
        except IndexError as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}. Index {idx} is out of range.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")


Essentially, the outcome of the code, it appends to my list no problem, but when I uncheck the checkbox, nothing happens, and this error comes out
line 208, in <lambda>
    item_widget.checkbox.stateChanged.connect(lambda state, idx=i: self.updateDisplayedDataFrames(idx, state == Qt.Checked))
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
in updateDisplayedDataFrames
    self.excelProcessor.listOfDisplayedDataFrames.remove(originalDf)
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled (both index and columns) DataFrame objects


Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take your time to follow the [tour], read [ask] and review the checklist. Then, consider that "it's not working" is not enough for us. You properly provided a traceback of the error, which is good, but have you actually done some proper research about that error? Numpy comparisons are tricky, instead of trying to fix the bug of a more complex program, you should try to focus on the problem itself. Start by trying to do what you do in updateDisplayedDataFrames with hardcoded values and do some related research.

why not have a single list with a field indicating if the frame is to be displayed or not ?
